# PermissionDenied package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, aws-lambda

I have an error trying to run the code

**EXTENSION Name: .package-lock.json    State: LaunchError  Events: []  Error Type: PermissionDenied**

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY nodejs-example-logs-api-extension/* .

RUN rm -rf package*.json

RUN chmod +x ./index.js
```

THE FULL ERROR IS:

```
Error: fork/exec /opt/extensions/.package-lock.json: permission denied
```

Comment: What exactly are you running that produces that error?  The Dockerfile you show doesn't have a `CMD` so just running it presumably wouldn't produce an error, and nothing you show here is obviously writing to an `/opt/extensions` directory.

Comment: the error is reported when you build image or run container?

Comment: @yong run container

Comment: @DavidMaze i using in lambda extension i heve two docker file 1 for lambda extension and 1 for lambda func . the /opt/extensions im using in lambda func .